# how to get a few items from the set?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

please help to get two of the three li. I use the following script:

```
import lxml.html

doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring("""
    <ul>
        <li>111</li>
        <li>222</li>
        <li>333</li>
    </ul>
""")
lis = doc.xpath('//li')
i = 0
result = []
for elem in lis:
    result.append(elem)
    i = i + 1
    if i > 1: break

print(result)
```

but I need to sample made ​​no xpath-expression and cycle, but only xpath-expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `position()` to reduce your XPath result set, eg:

```
result = doc.xpath('//li[position() <= 2]')
# [<Element li at 0x7f7728684530>, <Element li at 0x7f7728684590>]
```